# Manage SSL certificates in load balancer in Google cloud through custom/private node.js client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, gcp-load-balancer

I have this case where i want to manage the ssls in google cloud.
Manually i could just go to GCP > Network Services > Advanced menu > Certificates to manage the certificates.

I googled about http apis and i stumbled upon this [REST Resource: sslCertificates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates). but these apis only work through OAuth.

**Is there a way to access these apis through service acccounts ?**

I also looked at [GCP NPM](http://Cloud%20Node.js%20Client) and all its complimentary packages but none of them had functions to manage ssl in load balancers

moreover these packages dont have any function to initialse the service account at my own. they run only in google cloud environments like compute engine.

Please help

any kind of response is welcomed

Comment: 1/2) Service Accounts are OAuth in respect to the tokens that are generated. You can generate OAuth Access Tokens from both User Accounts and Service Accounts. Both generate an OAuth Access Token that is used in the HTTP `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>` header.

Comment: 2/2) Depending on the API and the resource, items like the `owner` of a resource such as a domain name are important. Service Accounts are typically not owners of domains, but they can be granted permission.

Comment: @JohnHanley could you refer me some code please

Comment: Google and Stackoverflow have numerous (hundreds) of examples. Google search.